# Search Options Help page link only available from deep inside of the FAQ page?

Tags: feature-request

The StackOverflow FAQ (https://stackoverflow.com/faq) has this faq entry:

> Are there any search options?
>   Indeed there are. Advanced Super Ninja Search Options no less. Visit the [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) to see them … but you must first snatch this pebble from my hand, grasshopper.

But shouldn't there be a "Search Help" link just to the right or underneath the Search field that points to the https://stackoverflow.com/search page?

There is precedence for something like this. Notice that the main Google page (http://www.google.com) has an Advanced Search (http://www.google.com/advanced_search?hl=en) link immediately to the right of the search field. This would help out users that are new to the StackOverflow site.

Thanks,

bg

Answer (score 1):

While there is no explicit link to help with the visibility, a blank search entry in the textbox will bring you straight to the Search Help page.

And as mmyers points out, there's also an additional link on the right sidebar when you enter a non-blank text search, whether it returns results or not.

Comment: There's also a link in the right-hand column of any page of search results.

Comment: @mmyers Good catch! It's only available for normal searches (ones that aren't pure tag-based), but then again you'd need to know the advanced search to know about pure tag searches.

Comment: (mmyers: thanks for fixing the links with your edit!)  Actually, my feature request concerns the fact that a user new to StackOverflow would not know about the help being hidden in both of those ways given (i.e., leaving the search field blank, or doing a search and then looking for help later).  

If a visual link will cramp page real-estate, how about having the temporary text in the field itself that reads "Leave this blank to see help page"?